# slackware iso download

Tags: download, iso-image, slackware

where can I download Slackware `.iso` Linux  ?.

from oldest til newest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably from one of the mirror site like

> http://slackware.mirrors.tds.net/pub/slackware/